# convert values from two columns into one new column

Tags: postgresql, date, ddl

I have two columns: year and month:

```
Year    Month
2017    01
2017    02
2018    12
2019    06
2020    07
```

With

```
select to_date(concat(Year, Month), 'YYYYMM') csv_date FROM my_table;
```

I can get just one column with `date` datatype.

How can I add this column in my table, to get this:

```
Year    Month   csv_date
2017    01      2017-01-00
2017    02      2017-02-00
2018    12      2018-12-00
2019    06      2019-06-00
2020    07      2020-07-00
```

Comment: Do you want to add new column to table or just select from table as you show in your last result?

Comment: I want to add a new column. Now I know only how to make these values with a `select`, but I don't know how to insert it in the table. Everything I've read wasn't exactly what I want, and I didn't understand too. I would like to do something equivalent as in pandas would be `df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: a_function_to_convert_to_date(row['Year'], row['Month']]))`

Answer (score 2):

You ***can not*** have a column defined as **date** that contains 00 for the day. That would be an invalid date, and Postgres will not allow it. The suggested method of concatenating the 2 works if the year and month are defined as a string type column, but the result will have '01' for the day. If those columns are defined as numeric then you can use the make date function.

```
with my_table(tyr, tmo, nyr,nmo) as 
   ( values ('2020', '04', 2020, 04 ) )
select to_date(concat(tyr, tmo), 'YYYYMM') txt_date
     , make_date(nyr,nmo,01) num_date  
  from my_table;
```

With that said then use the to_char function for a date column you can to get just year and month (and if you must) add the '-00'.  so

```
with my_table (adate) as 
   ( values ( date '2020-04-01') )
select adate, to_char(adate,'yyyy-mm') || '-00' as yyyymm
  from mytable;
```

If you are on v12 and want to add the column you can add it as a generated column. This will have the advantage that it cannot be updated independently but will automatically update when the source columns(s) get updated.  See fiddle complete [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bcd0adf4df4365873904fc29835870e5);

```
alter table my_table add column cvs_date date generated always as (make_date(yr, mo,01)) stored;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PostgreSQL Query

If you want to add new column then

```
alter table my_table add column csv_date date;

update my_table set csv_date=to_date(concat(Year, Month), 'YYYYMM');
```

If you want only select output then:

```
select year, month, to_date(concat(Year, Month), 'YYYYMM') csv_date FROM my_table;
```